# How to check if string is xxxxx.xxxx format in c#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string which is should be in xxxxx.xxxx format. My application is getting this string automatically and some time string looks like xxxx.xxxx or xxxxxx.xxx or ...

My question is "How to check if string is in correct format?"

I thought something like:

```
myString.Length == 10;
```

but it could be wrong if dot will be in wrong place...

Comment: Is it supposed to be numeric, or can there be any characters where the "x"s are?  Can the dot be in any of the 10 positions, or just those 2? In general, regular expressions are useful for checking if strings fit a certain pattern, you might want to search for RegEx examples.

Comment: Is `x` supposed to represent a digit 0-9?

Comment: Does the `.` always need to be in the same exact spot? Your second sentence sounds like it could vary. *We need more information!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a regular expression you could use:

```
\w{5}\x2E\w{4}

//      Alphanumeric, exactly 5 repetitions
//      Hex 2E (.)
//      Alphanumeric, exactly 4 repetitions
```

You should try Expresso from http://www.ultrapico.com

Comment: Assuming that the `.` should always be the 6th character. I'm not sure that the author doesn't actually just want a single `.` somewhere in the string between (probably) numbers.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of ambiguity in the question.  I made assumptions and gave the OP enough information to proceed.

Comment: Thanks=) That's what I looking for=) Comment: If you would put the whole if statement with code that shows how to use REGEX that's going to be more meaningful...

Comment: I'll give you seeds but I'm not going to pull your plow.

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking this will work:

```
if (myString.Length == 10 && myString.IndexOf('.') == 5)
{
    //do something


}
```

or

```
if (myString.Length == 10 && myString.CharAt(5) == '.')
{
    //do something


}
```

If 'x' must equal a alphanumeric character then this will work:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @"[A-z0-9]{5}\.[A-z0-9]{4}$");
if (match.Success)
{


    //do something
}
```

Comment: Instead of `IndexOf` check that index specifically.

Comment: what if the string is all `.`?

Comment: This could return true for `xxxxx.x.xx`

Comment: @Habib That is true. Regular expressions are usually well suited for this type of validation.

Comment: i was under the impression that 'x' is any ascii character but the CarAt(4) HAD to be a '.'. If that's the case, then 'xxxxx.x.xx' would match this. If this is not the case, then OP should define what 'x' can be!!

Comment: @crush I added a potential regex solution